# How to run all elementor builder script after initial page loading?

Tags: loading, builder, elementor, domcontentloaded

Elementor page builder script not loading with swup.js (ajax page loading system)

```
document.addEventListener(“DOMContentLoaded”, () => {

// I want to load all elementor page builder script here!!

});
```

Reference url
https://swup.js.org/getting-started/reloading-javascript

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction( 'init', function() {
 // Do something that is based on the elementorFrontend object.
} );
```

source: https://code.elementor.com/js-hooks/